# How to run make from make in loop when file change?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
MAKE=make

ALL: pl/index.html

pl/index.html: pl/index.md template.html
    build.js -l pl -t template.html > pl/index.html

watch: pl/index.html
    @inotifywait -e close_write pl/index.md template.html | while read events; do $(MAKE); done
```

what I want is to have `make watch` that will run make each time the file changes. But make stop the parent make after it finish.

I have this output after edit the file:

```
$ LC_ALL=C make watch 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/ssd/projects/jcubic/scheme/tutorial'
build.js -l pl -t template.html > pl/index.html
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/ssd/projects/jcubic/scheme/tutorial'
```

I've also tried:

`bash -c 'make'` and `` `make` `` the last one give error:

```
/bin/sh: make[1]:: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:9: watch] Error 127
```

is it possible to write `make watch`?

I've tried to write script:

```
#!/bin/bash

make
```

but calling the script with `./run` shows same error:

```
/bin/sh: make[1]:: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:9: watch] Error 127
```

calling `bash -c './run'` works but it stop after first run like the first error show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original attempt was correct.  Your problem doesn't have anything do with make or the makefile... you've simply invoked `inotifywait` incorrectly.

Since a makefile recipe is just shell commands, often it's helpful when debugging to run those commands directly at your shell prompt and see if they work.  If they do, then the problem is somewhere in your makefile.  If they don't, then the problem is somewhere else.

In this case the documentation for `inotifywait` makes it clear:

> It can either exit once an event occurs, or continually execute and output events as they occur.

And:

> -m, --monitor
>
> Instead of exiting after receiving a single event, execute indefinitely. The default behaviour is to exit after the first event occurs.

So the behavior you see is exactly as documented.  If you want `inotifywait` to wait forever, use the `-m` option.

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of `Entering directory` and `Leaving directory` message but keep executed command line?

Comment: Found it in [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Tricks-For-Silencing-Make.html) `make --no-print-directory`